# Calculate period return from monthly returns

Tags: r

This may sound naive but I can't seem to find the solution. I need to calculate 1, 3 and 5-year returns and my dataset consists of monthly returns rather than prices. The dataset I'm working on is similar to `managers`

```
data(managers)  
tail(managers) 
              HAM1    HAM2   HAM3    HAM4    HAM5    HAM6 EDHEC LS EQ SP500 TR US 10Y TR US 3m TR
2006-07-31 -0.0144 -0.0131 0.0102 -0.0120 -0.0164 -0.0225     -0.0031  0.00620   0.01580  0.00423
2006-08-31  0.0161 -0.0113 0.0253 -0.0183  0.0169  0.0193      0.0114  0.02380   0.02190  0.00441
2006-09-30  0.0068 -0.0231 0.0072  0.0197  0.0132 -0.0177      0.0001  0.02580   0.01140  0.00456
2006-10-31  0.0427  0.0167 0.0183  0.0518  0.0266  0.0189      0.0194  0.03260   0.00584  0.00381
2006-11-30  0.0117  0.0206 0.0269  0.0373  0.0038  0.0300      0.0200  0.01900   0.01419  0.00430
2006-12-31  0.0115 -0.0062 0.0110  0.0206  0.0317  0.0215      0.0153  0.01403  -0.01550  0.00441
```

I looked into the `Return.cumulative` from package `PerformanceAnalytics`  but there is no argument for specifying periods. `ROC` from `TTR` can specify the number of periods to use but it is not based on return. What would be the best way to do this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Wen I've looked into `PerformanceAnalytics` and `TTR` packages but couldn't find an appropriate function to calculate the period return from monthly returns.

Comment: How about my second question  log return(log(A/B) )or simple return(A-B/A)

Comment: @Wen Oh sorry! I just need the geometric return. I'm trying to compare the 1, 3 and 5-year returns between different indexes.

Comment: try to look at the code I posted I did not finish it all , cause you already know how to do next step, Ps: Sorry for the late posted , cause busy work ....

Comment: Please show your desired output from input data example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on what you want and what you know about `ROC` from `TTR`  , I will only provide the Data preparation part

*#Sample Data*

```
df=read.table(text=' Date    HAM1    HAM2   HAM3    HAM4    HAM5    HAM6  
              2006-07-31 -0.0144 -0.0131 0.0102 -0.0120 -0.0164 -0.0225     
              2006-08-31  0.0161 -0.0113 0.0253 -0.0183  0.0169  0.0193     
              2006-09-30  0.0068 -0.0231 0.0072  0.0197  0.0132 -0.0177     
              2006-10-31  0.0427  0.0167 0.0183  0.0518  0.0266  0.0189     
              2006-11-30  0.0117  0.0206 0.0269  0.0373  0.0038  0.0300     
              2006-12-31  0.0115 -0.0062 0.0110  0.0206  0.0317  0.0215    ',header=T,stringsAsFactors=F)
```

*#Make the Return to Price assume all stocks initial value with 100*

```
for (i in 2:dim(df)[2]){

B=Reduce(function(x,y) {x * (1+y)}, df[,i], init=100, accumulate=T)# if it is log Return: {x * exp(y)}
if (i==2){
   Price= B
}else{
    Price=cbind(Price,B)
}
}

Price=data.frame(cbind(df$Date,Price[-1,]))

names(Price)=names(df)

> Price
        Date             HAM1             HAM2             HAM3             HAM4             HAM5             HAM6
1 2006-07-31            98.56            98.69           101.02             98.8            98.36            97.75
2 2006-08-31       100.146816        97.574803       103.575806         96.99196       100.022284        99.636575
3 2006-09-30   100.8278143488    95.3208250507   104.3215518032     98.902701612   101.3425781488    97.8730076225
4 2006-10-31 105.133162021494 96.9126828290467 106.230636201199 104.025861555502 104.038290727558 99.7228074665652
5 2006-11-30 106.363220017145  98.909084095325 109.088240315011 107.906026191522 104.433636232323 102.714491690562
6 2006-12-31 107.586397047342  98.295847773934 110.288210958476 110.128890331067 107.744182500887 104.922853261909
```

Then you can use the normal package to annualized the return(or customize)

Comment: It is a bit more complicated that I would think but I get the idea and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: For sure , I guess you are doing some stock trend analysis , it is always better keeping the price rather than return , in case you need standardize your data, or even get the moving average for stock price

Answer (score 0):

Using @Wen's data:

```
df=read.table(text=' Date    HAM1    HAM2   HAM3    HAM4    HAM5    HAM6  
          2006-07-31 -0.0144 -0.0131 0.0102 -0.0120 -0.0164 -0.0225     
          2006-08-31  0.0161 -0.0113 0.0253 -0.0183  0.0169  0.0193     
          2006-09-30  0.0068 -0.0231 0.0072  0.0197  0.0132 -0.0177     
          2006-10-31  0.0427  0.0167 0.0183  0.0518  0.0266  0.0189     
          2006-11-30  0.0117  0.0206 0.0269  0.0373  0.0038  0.0300     
          2006-12-31  0.0115 -0.0062 0.0110  0.0206  0.0317  0.0215    ',header=T,stringsAsFactors=F)
```

You can use the `rollaply` function from the `zoo` package.

```
library(zoo)
roll <- function(x, n, stat) {
  if (length(x) <= n) NA
  else x <- x + 1
    rollapply(x, list(-seq(n)), stat, fill = NA)
}

df2 <- transform(df, four_month_return_HAM1 = ave(HAM1, FUN = function(x) roll(x, 4, prod)-1))
```

Change 4 to the period you want to calculate the cumulative return over. So, for one year, this would be 12. This will then give you the 12 month rolling returns.

Comment: So you do the `average` to return ?

Comment: @Wen, I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: `ave(HAM1, FUN = function(x) roll(x, 4, prod)-1)` For this part , mean of return

Comment: Im taking the product of the prior 4 periods (in this case months) and subtracting 1 to get the cumulative return of the prior 4 periods.